How do you import the name ‘Aer’ from qiskit?
I ran this code on Jupyter Notebook:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
from math import sqrt
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = execute(qc, simulator).result()
statevector = result.get_statevector()
print(statevector)

And it gave me this error:
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
      2 from math import sqrt
      3 qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit'

Question: How do you import the name Aer from qiskit?

Qiskit Aer is now a separate package. You need to first install it by, for example, running on a notebook cell:
!pip install qiskit-aer
Then you can import Aer by executing:
from qiskit_aer import Aer
